# Free Monad for AST > 1-arity?

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, category-theory

When I'm saying `1-arity | 2-arity | n-arity`, I'm referring to tree in grap theory [k-ary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree) :

> a k-ary tree is a rooted tree in which each node has no more than k children

I have been using Free Monad in my project to create a small eDSL in haskell... but all the example I have seen are only 1-ary tree (Linear AST) like this one :

[image]

this datatype lift on `Free` Monad :

```
data Toy b next =
    Output b next
  | Bell next
  | Done
```

I would like to implement a more complex eDSL than a Linear one... Is Free Monad a solution for that ? and if yes, do you have examples of Free Monad > 1-Ary  ?

Comment: By '> 1-Arity`, what exactly do you mean? I haven't seen the word 'arity' used in this context before.

Comment: I have added some definition @bradrn :-) Thanks

Comment: Thanks! So you mean like e.g. `data Toy b next = ... | Operation next next`, where `next` appears twice?

Comment: yeah exactly :-)

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what that would do. I tried experimenting in GHCi but couldn't get the `Show` instance to work properly. Then again I've never used free monads so I'm probably not the best person to answer this question. (By the way, could you edit in an example of a 2-arity eDSL? I know I was able to figure it out but I feel it's still not too obvious from the question...)

Comment: Can you clarify: are you trying to figure out how to represent conditionals and loops in an eDSL expressed as a free monad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The representation and composition of trees with a generalized notion of arity is in fact one of the core features of free monads.

For example, binary trees can be defined as a free monad as follows:

```
data BinF a = Node a a
type Bin = Free BinF

node :: Bin a -> Bin a -> Bin a
node l r = Free (Node l r)

example :: Bin Int
example = node (node (pure 0)
                     (pure 1))
               (pure 2)
{-
  +---+---0
   \   \--1
    \-2
 -}
```

An isomorphic representation is

```
data BinF a = Node (Bool -> a)
{- The product type (a, a) is isomorphic to (Bool -> a). -}
```

The idea behind this is that a tree node can be seen as a demand for input (in this case, an input of type `Bool`), which is used to select one of the children of the node. Thus, a binary tree can be seen as a parser of bitstreams.

```
type Bin = Free BinF

nextBit :: Bin Bool
nextBit = Free (Node (\b -> Pure b))

example :: Bin Int
example = do
  b1 <- nextBit
  if b1 then do
    b2 <- nextBit
    if b2 then
      pure 0
    else
      pure 1
  else
    pure 2
```

Of course, you can represent other arities by changing the `Bool` type (or the number of fields of `Node` in the original formulation).

For a more practical example, [the pipes library is build around such a free monad](https://blog.poisson.chat/posts/2018-04-26-pipes-free-monad.html).